# Remove white background outside an object but keep the white in the inside using Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, image-trace, white

i want to know how to Remove the white background outside an object but keep the white in the inside using Illustrator. please see the video below to understand more. when I want to remove the white background, it's all removed, I want to keep the black background inside the ghost.

[click to see the youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCcN9SWHKBk)

Comment: You get a faster answer if you dont rely on a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a little late, but useful for the future maybe.

Usually you'd select the open path and hit ctrl/cmd+J to close the path, however what you have is two separate compound shapes so that won't work.

What you can do is draw a path between the gap and then include it in the divide, then you can delete the background separately.

I recorded a [quick vid](https://vimeo.com/747611853) to demonstrate

Comment: I tried another solution but yours is the best, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Was this an image trace done? on the right side top near the hat there is an unclosed path. after closing that and any other open areas, Pathfinder > Divide should work

Comment: I think this is the solution but how to close the unclosed path on the right side top near the hat?